# Choosing a root node based on key value

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Is it possible to choose a d3.hierarchy root node based on a JSON key value?  For example, I'd like the root node in the following JSON object to be "B1" instead of "A1" - I would need to be able to access this based on the value of `name`

```
{
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "value": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe using d3.filter() ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution here involves pure JavaScript, no D3 method needed.

As you know, [`d3.hierarchy`](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy)...

> Constructs a root node from the specified hierarchical data. The specified data must be an object representing the root node.

That being said, all you need is to specify the correct object.

For example, using your whole object (not what you want):

```js
const data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "B1",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "B1-C1",
          "value": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

const root = d3.hierarchy(data);

console.log(root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Now let's get the object you want. This can be easily done with `Array.prototype.find`:

```
const root = d3.hierarchy(data.children.find(d => d.name === "B1"));
```

And here is the demo:

```js
const data = {
  "name": "A1",
  "children": [{
    "name": "B1",
    "children": [{
      "name": "B1-C1",
      "value": 50
    }]
  }]
};

const root = d3.hierarchy(data.children.find(d => d.name === "B1"));

console.log(root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it works great for the example I provided.  What if I needed to search the entire hierarchy that could be many levels deep?  For example if I needed to find a name that was `data.children.children` ?  Is there a way to do a deep find?

Comment: Yes, there is. Just do a search here, if you don't find anything you can post a new question. But I'm pretty sure that such questions already exist.